# Python "[x] * n" style array creation?

Tags: python, arrays

Does this style of array creation "**[x] * n + [y] * k**" return a string or an array?
Can someone explain how this method exactly work? I am new to Python. I apologize if this question is too simple. I just didn't know how to search for this method using Google.

Comment: these are not arrays, these are lists. to check the type of an object, just use `type(some_object)` and you could see for yourself...

Comment: That expression will create a list that looks like `[x, x, ..., x, x, y, y, .... y, y]`

Comment: this is the "repetition" operator, it works on different sequences, so a `str` object and `list` (**not array**) objects are both sequences, and they both work with the repetition operator.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Wow. That's actually really helpful. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work for creating a list.

```
n = 10
k = 20
['x'] * n + ['y'] * k
Output: ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']
```

If you want to turn that into a string, use this: `''.join(['x'] * n + ['y'] * k)`. `.join()` [returns a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

I'll break down what each part of `['x'] * n + ['y'] * k` means.

`['x']` and `['y']` are lists with one item.

`* n` and `* k` essentially repeats the list `n` and `k` times. so if `n` was 5, `['x'] * n` would look like `['x','x','x','x','x']`.

Finally, the `+` merges both lists so the results of `['x'] * n` and `['y'] * k` are in one list, so if `n` was 10 and `k` was 20, you would get `['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']` if you just used that method and `'xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'` if you used `.join()`.

Comment: If you want a string then just remove the brackets around the strings: `'x' * n + 'y'* k`. No need for `str.join`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! The method you provided for turning this into string helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score -5):

The first question is what is your x and y.
if you want to creat a string, use string 'x' and 'y'.

```
['x'] * n + ['y'] * k
```

if you wang to creat a list(array), just asign a class to x and y.like:

```
x, y = object(), object()
[x] * n + [y] * m
```

Comment: You will never create a string with your first method.

Comment: `['x'] * n + ['y'] * k` does not create a string, it creates a list. you aren't assigning a "class" to `x` and `y`, you are assigning objects, instances of the base object class, but note, `str` objects are objects too...